# docker-compose + external container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have started a docker container with the following command

```
docker run --name mysql --restart always -p 3306:3306 -v /var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d mysql:5.7.14
```

and then would like to connect a wordpress site with the following docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '2'

services:
    wordpress:
        image: wordpress
        external_links:
            - mysql:mysql
        ports:
            - 80:80
    environment:
        WORDPRESS_DB_USER: root
        WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
        - /var/www/somesite.com:/var/www/html
```

But I keep getting the following error

```
Starting somesitecom_wordpress_1
Attaching to somesitecom_wordpress_1
wordpress_1  | 
wordpress_1  | Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in - on line 19
wordpress_1  | 
wordpress_1  | MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection refused
```

It seems like the `external_links` isn't working.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your link is working, but you're on separate networks inside of Docker. From the [docker-compose.yml docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external-links):

> Note: If you’re using the version 2 file format, the externally-created containers must be connected to at least one of the same networks as the service which is linking to them.

To solve this, you can create your own network:

```
docker network create dbnet
docker network connect dbnet mysql
```

Then configure your docker-compose.yml with:

```
version: '2'

networks:
  dbnet:
    external:
      name: dbnet

services:
    wordpress:
        image: wordpress
        ports:
            - 80:80
        environment:
            WORDPRESS_DB_USER: root
            WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
        volumes:
            - /var/www/somesite.com:/var/www/html
        networks:
          - dbnet
```

Note with recent versions of Docker, you shouldn't need to link the containers, the DNS service should do the name resolution for you.

Comment: @AlexanderKim you need to create an external network first. The connect command is only needed if you don't want to remove the mysql container, otherwise you'd just specify the network in the run command.

Comment: i mean docker-compose file, there's networks: section right after `version: '2'` in your example.

Comment: @AlexanderKim probably yes, but pay attention to your compose file version because the syntax has changed in newer versions. I include the external name in case others have a different name for their external network than inside the compose file.