# docker-compose doesnt automatically connect to external network

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am having trouble with multiple stacks joining the same network with docker-compose. I am using portainer to manage my containers, and it currently only supports `docker-compose.yml` files with format version 2.0 and I assume that may be where the issues arise from.

When I create a stack with docker-compose named fx `stack1`, it expectedly creates a network for the containers within to communicate named the same as the stack just with a `_default` suffix automatically, so `stack1_default`. If I then want to create a second stack named `stack2`, which I want to connect to and use the same network created by `stack1` I would, according to the docker-compose docs [Use a pre-existing network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#use-a-pre-existing-network), simple append:

```
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: stack1_default
```

to the `docker-compose.yml` file of `stack2` and also

```
    networks:
      - stack1_default
```

to the individual services defined. But a network for `stack2` named `stack2_default` is then still being created regardless and I cannot connect between containers that are not defined in the same yml file. I can see in portainer that the containers launched in stack2 has not joined the `stack1_default` network. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39068043/8575867) to a similar post, I have to use `docker network connect` to connect a container to a network manually anyways. Then I can ping by container name just fine.

So my question is: Do I really have to manually connect them and why is it so? I would assume that it wouldn't create a new network, since I explicitly asked to join an already existing network. Then there is really not much purpose for me to use docker-compose.

Comment: Hi, can you share how this external network is created?

Comment: By docker-compose when starting `stack1`